HTML: change the point at which you arrive on the page
I have a wordpress website and I'd like it so that when a user arrives on the page, instead of arriving at the top of the page, I want them to be automatically in the centre of the page. I don't know if this is very clear, so please don't hesitate to ask me any questions.
On the wordpress site, I have PHP code and a banner that was already created.
I've already tried poking around on wordpress or looking for HTML tags that can do what I want, with no success unfortunately. Do you have any ideas that might help me?

Use an ID and a hash. Use javascript to test if there is a hash in the URL

You can use init hook of wordpress here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/ and then do the code to reach to the center of page.
